# React query mutation typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm just playing around with react-query

with typescript

I mean I do my first attempts

Is it the right way?

```
const useCreateTodo = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return useMutation(
    (todo: TodoDto) => axios.post(`${URL}/todos`, todo).then((res) => res.data),
    {
      onMutate: async (newTodo: TodoDto) => {
        // Cancel any outgoing refetches (so they don't overwrite our optimistic update)
        await queryClient.cancelQueries("todos");

        // Snapshot the previous value
        const previousTodos = queryClient.getQueryData("todos");

        // Optimistically update to the new value
        queryClient.setQueryData<TodoDto[] | undefined>("todos", (old) =>
          old ? [...old, newTodo] : old
        );

        // Return a context object with the snapshotted value
        return { previousTodos };
      },
      // If the mutation fails, use the context returned from onMutate to roll back
      onError: (
        err,
        newTodo,
        context:
          | {
              previousTodos: unknown;
            }
          | undefined
      ) => {
        queryClient.setQueryData(
          "todos",
          context ? context.previousTodos : context
        );
      },
      // Always refetch after error or success:
      onSettled: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries("todos");
      },
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

optimistic updates are a bit tricky for type inference. There is now an example for this exact case [in the docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/examples/optimistic-updates-typescript).

From that example:

```
const addTodoMutation = useMutation(
    newTodo => axios.post('/api/data', { text: newTodo }),
    {
      // When mutate is called:
      onMutate: async (newTodo: string) => {
        setText('')
        // Cancel any outgoing refetches (so they don't overwrite our optimistic update)
        await queryClient.cancelQueries('todos')

        // Snapshot the previous value
        const previousTodos = queryClient.getQueryData<Todos>('todos')

        // Optimistically update to the new value
        if (previousTodos) {
          queryClient.setQueryData<Todos>('todos', {
            ...previousTodos,
            items: [
              ...previousTodos.items,
              { id: Math.random().toString(), text: newTodo },
            ],
          })
        }

        return { previousTodos }
      },
      // If the mutation fails, use the context returned from onMutate to roll back
      onError: (err, variables, context) => {
        if (context?.previousTodos) {
          queryClient.setQueryData<Todos>('todos', context.previousTodos)
        }
      },
      // Always refetch after error or success:
      onSettled: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries('todos')
      },
    }
  )
```

A couple of explanations:

- Basically, you want to set the type definition only on `onMutate`, so that type inference will work for the `mutateFn` (`newTodo` is inferred) as well as for the context in `onError`.
- add generics for `getQueryData` so that `previousTodos` is typed. You don't need to union with `undefined` though - react-query will do that for you.
- the functional updater for `setQueryData` is tricky, because it requires you to return an Array, but `old` can be undefined. I prefer to use the `previousTodos` returned by `getQueryData`

Comment: Is it fine to call `useQueryClient` inside a custom hook, like this?

const useCreateTodo = () => {
  'const queryClient = useQueryClient();'
  
  return useMutation(...);
}

Comment: yes, definitely. `useQueryClient` is just react-context :)

Comment: Wouldn't setting the type on axios' `post` be a more complete example?
 The mutationFn would be:
`(newTodo: <Pick<Todo, 'text'>) => axios.post<Todo>('/api/todos', { data: newTodo})`